# Stone vs. Atomic Bomb

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, energy, nuclear-physics, estimation

What would do more damage, a B53, a 9 megaton uranium bomb, or a medium sized stone (2 kg) stone throw at 90% the speed of light. One thing that I know that will have to be considered is that fact that at high speeds the air doesn't move out of the way and undergoes fusion with the stone. If the stone does more damage, how much bigger would the atomic bomb have to be to match it. If the bomb does more damage, how much faster would the stone have to be thrown to match it.

Comment: Not sure what "9 megaton uranium bomb" is supposed to mean, but the only bombs ever made with that much energy are Teller-Ulam devices (Google it) which are somewhat more sophisticated than a simple fission device.

Comment: @jameslarge I don't think it was a Teller-Ulam device, but you could look it up. I would be interested to know more about the bomb, and an answer that described how it may differ from a basic uranium fission bomb deserves +2 points.

Comment: This is wonderfully answered by Randall Munroe, [Relativistic Baseball](https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/)

Comment: @Jimmy360 you don't think _what_ was a Teller-Ulam device?  The Teller-Ulam design (colloquially known as the H-bomb) was first tested in the early 50's (Google for "Ivy Mike" and "Castle Bravo").  Pretty much all nuclear weapons that still exist today are Teller-Ulam devices.

Comment: http://nuclearweaponarchive.org/Library/Teller.html

Comment: @jameslarge It isn't an H bomb, and it has been decommissioned since the Cold War.

Comment: @jameslarge I know what Teller-Ulam device is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us calculate the energies. For the bomb, [Google gives](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=9+megatons+of+TNT+in+joules) $3.8\times 10^{16}\,\text{J}$. For the stone, we use the Einstein equation
$$KE=mc^2(\gamma-1)\qquad\gamma\equiv\sqrt{1-\beta^2}^{-1};\quad \beta=v/c$$
Plugging in the numbers, this gives a stone energy of $3.8\times 10^{18}\,\text{J}$. The stone is actually more powerful than the bomb. This is roughly 100 times greater than the energy of the bomb.

Comment: I asked that an answer account for the fusion. If this this is impossible, however, tell me.

Comment: @Jimmy360 I don't see what fusion has to do with this. Are you talking about nuclear fusion?

Comment: From my understanding, aerodynamics doesn't apply at this speed. The air will fuse with the stone, producing bursts of gamma rays and scattered particles.

Comment: @Jimmy360 If that happens, the effect will surely be negligible considering the stone is so heavy on a particle physics scale. This calculation is 100% valid if the stone is shot out of a slingshot, through a vacuum tube and onto a target.

Comment: But, what would the added output be. I don't wan to use a vacuum tube system because one of the things about the question that I want to know is how the fusion will affect it.

Comment: @Jimmy360 Do you have a source for this fusion effect?

Comment: https://what-if.xkcd.com/20/

Comment: https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/

Comment: It won't let my do @0celo7

Comment: and as you found http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~sdalessi/Tunguska.pdf @0celo7

Comment: Oh, be the way, I changed it to 90%. At very high speeds, it just doesn't fuse anymore. @0celo7

Comment: You forgot a factor of c in the equation and you must subtract m c^2 because only the kinetic energy is available. You then find that the stone has more kinetic energy.

Comment: @CountIblis Yes, thank you. I can't believe I forgot that.